# Azure Role - Application startup task failed with exit code 1

Tags: azure

I tried to include a Task as per MSDN article below: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154098.aspx

However I'm getting the error below on one of the instance;

*Recycling (Waiting for role to start... Application startup task failed with exit code 1. [2013-04-13T11:03:22Z])*

Could someone please suggest what's really happening and what's the fix if any?

Below is my cmd:

```
@echo off

@echo Installing "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
%windir%\System32\ServerManagerCmd.exe -install Web-IP-Security

@echo Unlocking configuration for "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" feature 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/security
```

And CSDF:

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated"/>      
  <Task commandLine="startup\startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated"/>
</Startup>
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this happen locally or when deploying to Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do here is RDP into the instance and run the .CMD file manually to see if it's throwing any errors.

I received a similar error when deploying to Azure and it was caused by the startup command raising a dialogue box that required a user input. Essentially the alert box was confirming that a .dll had been registered, that's all, but it was enough to stop the deployment routine in it's tracks.

Here is the contents of my .cmd file:

```
chcp 1252>NUL
regsvr32 /s .\library\asppdf64.dll
regsvr32 /s .\library\aspjpeg64.dll
exit /b 0
```

The `/s` tells the service to run silently (i.e. with dialogues purged). The `chcp 1252>NUL` sets the code-page.

Comment: thank you, I've updated my original question. It happens when deploying to azure and I've got TWO Tasks. Not sure if azure supports many tasks.

Comment: Yes you can have multiple tasks in a single script but as long as they execute silently they won't stop the App Fabric Controller from completing the deployment.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem once. I fixed it by adding the following to my start-up script:

```
exit /b 0
```

Without this the Azure Fabric didn't register the script as finished and it kept recycling the instance.

I see you use *ServerManagerCmd.exe*. This command is removed from Windows Server 2012. So make sure your role isn't deployed with the latest OS Family version.

```
<ServiceConfiguration ... osFamily="1" ...>
```